# Set Defaults CSS Scripts via Overriding

Tags: css

I have the following css script in my shared css,

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
    border-top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    border:none;
 }
```

However I need to override first three line of scripts to disable accordion content.

That is what I want:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
       /* padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
        border-top: 0;
        overflow: auto;*/
        border:none;
     }
```

I know how to override the first one as follows:

override

```
padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
```

to

```
padding:0!important;
```

but I do not know for the second (`border-top: 0;`) and third (`overflow: auto;`)

Comment: can't you just set border-top and overflow to what you want them to be?  Such as `border-top: none;`  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

`.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{
    padding:0;
    border-top:none; 
    overflow:visible;
}`

This will set everything to their default values.

Comment: If you can use the snippet provided and call that after the original is called you shouldn't need to (unless something else is overriding it).

My suggestion is to try it without !important first and if for some reason that doesn't work, let us know with more detail so we can figure out why.  And as a last resort use !important.  It's good practice to avoid !important when you can, instead of using it as an easy fix.